# Use Next.js Image to render blob data / objectUrl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file-upload, next.js

I am using next.js to preview images users uploaded to my server. I fetch the images from the server at runtime. Serverside I create a readstream and send it to the client. The image path is stored in my database.

```js
    // Server
    const imageBuffer = fs.createReadStream(pathFromDb)
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", myFileType);
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
        imageBuffer.pipe(res);
        imageBuffer.on("end", resolve);
      });
```

On clientside I fetch the image and create an obectUrl with URL.createObjectURL which I then use in my img. I then get the lint warning, that I should use the next.js Image instead of html img.

I can´t figure out how I would solve the task with the next.js native Image. Is it even possible / are there some benefits? Are there better/other approaches then using a blob / objectUrl ? I feel like I am missing a general concept here.

```js
    // Client
    [...]
    const [src, setSrc] = useState("")
    const getFile = () => {
       const fileRes = await fetch(`/api/myFile/{fileId}`, {
          method: "GET",
       });
       const fileBlob = await fileRes.blob();
       const src = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
       setSrc(src)
    }   
 
    return(
       <img src={src}/>
    )
```